# Windows Partition won't show up during installing

Tags: 11.04, installation

I created empty space in my hard drive so I can install ubuntu. But when I go to the installation screen, there is no option to install alongside Windows. When I choose custom, the hard drive shows up as completely blank! I tried the USB way, tried turning the HDD back to IDE from AHCI, but no hope. I don't want to install inside windows because I want to be able to access Windows files from ubuntu. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a small error in the partition table - if that is the case all seems to work but the partition editor refuses to touch it.

I'd suggest you remove the new partition using the original program (hopefully there won't be any more errors), then firing up Ubuntu LiveCD and using GParted to make the new partition.

Comment: I realized this hard drive is set on a GUID partition table because I got this hard drive from a mac and installed Windows on it. GParted shows the disk as empty.

Comment: @TonyIto Post that into the question please

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by partition table corruption.  Use `sudo fdisk -lu` to inspect the partition table and look for partitions that either overlap, or extend beyond the end of the disk.

Comment: The partitions seem fine, but I realized it was GUID partition table instead of MBR for some reason. Maybe that is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [fixparts](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) to wipe the GPT info